# Is there a list of bills in the reign of George III & onwards?

Tags: law, united-kingdom, government, historical-research, industrial-history

I am researching the history of trackways, canals mines and railways from the reign of George 3rd through to the end of Queen Victoria’s reign. Is there a list of all bills presented to Parliament during that quite long timespan. I am interested in both bills that were presented and not passed as well as those that received their Royal Assent.

Comment: https://www.parliament.uk/business/bills-and-legislation/current-bills/previous-bills/ only goes back to 2001, but I'd expect someone at the UK parliament can provide you with a list that goes further back in time.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have contacted them and asked my question there.

Comment: In case they don't reply back, try to locate one or more people on LinkedIn who work for the UK parliament's archives department. And if all else fails, don't forget that there's a [freedom of information act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2000/36/contents) in the UK too.

Comment: To confirm that after I contacted them I got a very quick and helpfull reply. It has given me a great deal of excellent material to read through